Developing Statistical Analysis in web with flask
My project is following: we have some product shop and  customers  are going to choose  any product and write a comment, we might have hundreds of comments per day and the manager of the shop decided to analyze those comments, determine their polarity and  return  whether it is positive or negative and also  show those result graphically in order to  keep his buisness  active and effective.
The project consists of two parts:
Part  1:  we have to build a webpage which shows  possibility for  users to write a comment
Part 2: using python and flask  we should be able to connect  form,  retrieve  those comments and using transformers  determine  their polarity
First part and second part was succesfully implemented using following codes.
First one is html part:
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Sell Weapons</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
                <label for="comment1">evaluate first product</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="comment1" name="comment1" required="required"><br>
                  <label for="comment2">evaluate second product</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="comment2" name="comment2" required="required"><br>
                  <label for="comment3">evaluate third product</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="comment3" name="comment3" required="required"><br>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            
             <h4 style="color:Violet;">
               {{ prediction_text }} </h4>
            
            
            </body>
            </html>

Result is:
filling form
Based on this form, I have created following app.py file:
            import numpy as np
            from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,render_template
            import pickle
            from transformers import pipeline
            from collections import Counter
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
            app =Flask(__name__)
            @app.route('/')
            def home():
                return render_template("Commenting.html")
            
            @app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
            # @app.route('/')
            def predict():
                text =  [x for x in request.form.values()]
                print(text)
                status = []
                for sentence in text:
                    print(sentence)
                    status.append(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0]['label'])
                print(status)
                # data = {'Task': 'Hours per Day', 'Work': 22, 'Eat': 4, 'Commute': 6, 'Watching TV': 5, 'Sleeping': 15}
                data = Counter(status)
                print(data)
                data ={"Positive":list(data.values())[0],"Negative":list(data.values())[1]}
                positive_text =list(data .keys())[0]
                positive_frequency =list(data .values())[0]
                negative_text = list(data.keys())[1]
                negative_frequency = list(data.values())[1]
                total =positive_frequency+negative_frequency
                text_sho =(f'{positive_text}  takes {positive_frequency/(positive_frequency+negative_frequency)*100 } % '
                           f'and {negative_text} takes {negative_frequency/(positive_frequency+negative_frequency)*100} %')
            
                # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
                # status = []
                # for sentence in text:
                #     status.append(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0]['label'])
                #     # print(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0])
                # emotion_counter = Counter(status)
                # plt.pie([float(v) for v in emotion_counter.values()], labels=[k for k in emotion_counter],
                #         autopct="%2.3f%%")
                # plt.savefig("templates/sentiment_distribution.png")
                # plt.show()
                # values =[float(v) for v in emotion_counter.values()]
                # labels = [k for k in emotion_counter]
                #
            
                # text=list(text)
                return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=text_sho)
                # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
                # result =sentiment_pipeline(text)[0]
                # if result['label']=='POSITIVE':
                #     return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is positive')
                # else:
                #     return render_template('Commenting.html', prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is not positive')
            if __name__ =="__main__":
                app.run()

When we run it, we get the following  result: result
How can I generate a chart? I use several chart.js files, like this:
chart
But how to apply it in my project?

Your question title is not very relevant to the question you are asking. Also flask has little to do with charts except serving the generated content through it.
Showing charts to the user could be accomplished by;

generating an image (with matplotlib, seaborn, ...) and embedding that image in the html. Simple, static.
using several js libraries out there, including the one you mentioned (chart.js). Harder, better ux, interactivity etc.

Depending on your choice, you have to adjust your app to serve the static content. One approach might be creating an image and saving that image in the static folder and then using flask's send_from_directory function to show it in the html.
Js libraries all differ, so you'll need to read their documentation and integrate them with flask.

i will create image and save it, could you please show me send_from_directory example?

So here is my solution, original html  code  has been changed  as  :
     <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Sell Weapons</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
                    <label for="comment1">evaluate first product</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="comment1" name="comment1" required="required"><br>
                      <label for="comment2">evaluate second product</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="comment2" name="comment2" required="required"><br>
                      <label for="comment3">evaluate third product</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="comment3" name="comment3" required="required"><br>
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

                 <h4 style="color:Violet;">
                   {{ prediction_text }} </h4>
<img src= "{{url_for('static', filename='/Image/sentiment_distribution.png')}}" >

                </body>
                </html>

and corresponding app.py file  has been changed as  :
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,render_template,send_from_directory
import pickle
from transformers import pipeline
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
app =Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("Commenting.html")

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
# @app.route('/')
def predict():
    text =  [x for x in request.form.values()]
    print(text)
    status = []
    for sentence in text:
        print(sentence)
        status.append(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0]['label'])
    print(status)
    # data = {'Task': 'Hours per Day', 'Work': 22, 'Eat': 4, 'Commute': 6, 'Watching TV': 5, 'Sleeping': 15}
    data = Counter(status)
    print(data)
    if  "POSITIVE" in status and  "NEGATIVE" in status :
        data ={"Positive":list(data.values())[0],"Negative":list(data.values())[1]}
    elif  "POSITIVE" in status and "NEGATIVE"not  in status:
        data = {"Positive": list(data.values())[0], "Negative": 0}
    else :
        data = {"Positive": 0, "Negative": list(data.values())[0]}
    positive_text =list(data .keys())[0]
    positive_frequency =list(data .values())[0]
    negative_text = list(data.keys())[1]
    negative_frequency = list(data.values())[1]
    total =positive_frequency+negative_frequency
    text_sho =(f'{positive_text}  takes {positive_frequency/(positive_frequency+negative_frequency)*100 } % '
               f'and {negative_text} takes {negative_frequency/(positive_frequency+negative_frequency)*100} %')

    # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
    # status = []
    # for sentence in text:
    #     status.append(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0]['label'])
    #     # print(sentiment_pipeline(sentence)[0])
    # emotion_counter = Counter(status)
    plt.pie([float(v) for v in data.values()], labels=[k for k in data],
            autopct="%2.3f%%")
    plt.savefig("static/Image/sentiment_distribution.png")
    # plt.show()
    # values =[float(v) for v in emotion_counter.values()]
    # labels = [k for k in emotion_counter]
    #

    # text=list(text)
    return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=text_sho)
    # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
    # result =sentiment_pipeline(text)[0]
    # if result['label']=='POSITIVE':
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is positive')
    # else:
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html', prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is not positive')
if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run()

when we run it, we got the folloiwng  result :

so problem has been solved
